# Why this code returns a NaN?

Tags: javascript

```js
function m(age) {
  this.d = second;
}

function second() {
  var k = 65 - this.age;
  return k;
}

var asd = new m(20);
document.write(asd.d());
```

Why this code doesn't print out `45`? I think I did almost same as [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lQEtgFnZTY&list=PL46F0A159EC02DF82&index=27), but mine doesn't work.

Please also explain why I don't need '()' after second here?:

```
function m(age) {
    this.d = second;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the `age` parameter passed to the constructor to `this.age` so that referencing `this.age` refers to it properly later. Otherwise, as in your code, the `age` parameter is passed but never used and subsequently discarded:

```js
function m(age) {
  this.age = age;
  this.d = second;
}

function second() {
  var k = 65 - this.age;
  return k;
}

var asd = new m(20);
document.write(asd.d());
```

You might consider using a linter - the [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) rule would have alerted you to the problem.

Comment: i got it thank you but, if i swap points this.age = age; and this.d = second; it is correct though, why? when i assign age parameter to 'this.age' after 'this.d = second'

Comment: It doesn't matter which line runs first in the constructor, because regardless, the constructor will finish running all of its lines before `asd.d()` is called - see how your `new m(20)` is *above* `asd.d()` in your code. If you *called* `second` *before* you assigned to `this.age`, it would indeed result in the attempted access of `this.age` evaluating to `undefined`.\

Comment: `function m(age) {
  this.d = second;
  this.age = age;
}`
i meant this, look, i called second and then assigned age parameter  to `this.age` but it also works

Comment: You aren't *calling* second there - as you can see, there are no parentheses. Function invocations require parentheses, like `second()`. All you're doing is assigning `this.d` a *reference* of `second`, such that calling `.d()` will call `second()` (with the new calling context)